# Reference passing is changing the values of a matrix

Tags: pointers, matrix, fortran90, subroutine

I'm trying to make a code in Fortran90 (compiling with ifort) in which I multiply two matrices. I'm *writing* code for this because one of the matrices is sparse, so you can do the multiplication without allocating memory for the whole matrix.

I have two subroutines. The first one, multiplies the sparse matrix (`k` in diagonal, and `l` at both sides of the diagonal) and a vector (`b`). The result is passed to the main function trough  pointer `r`. I chose using subroutines and no functions because with this, I don't need to allocate memory again inside the subroutine.

```
    subroutine matSparXVec(k, l, b, r)

    implicit none
    real, intent(in)        ::k, l
    real, intent(in), dimension(:)  ::b
    real, intent(out), dimension(:) ::r
    integer             ::ierr, i

    r = (/&
        k*b(1)+l*b(2), &
        (l*b(i-1)+k*b(i)+l*b(i+1),i=2,size(b)-1),& 
        l*b(size(b)-1)+k*b(size(b))&
        /)

end subroutine matSparXVec
```

The second subroutine uses the first one to multiply a sparse matrix (`k`, `l`) with another matrix (`B`):

```
subroutine matSparXMat(k, l, B, R)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in)            ::k, l
    real, intent(in), dimension(:,:)    ::B
    real, intent(out), dimension(:,:)   ::R

    call  matsparXVec(k, l, B(1, :), R(1, :))
    R(1, :) = R(1, :) + l * B(1, :)

    do i = 2, (size(R)-2)
        call matsparXVec(k,l,B(i,:),R(i,:))
        R(i,:)=R(i-1,:)+R(i,:)
    enddo 

    call matsparXVec(k,l,B(size(B),:),R(size(R),:))
    R(size(R),:) = R(size(R),:) + l * B(size(B)-1,:)


end subroutine matSparXmat
```

Now the issue is that, in some place of the subroutine `matSparXmat`, I'm modifying the data pointed by `B(:,:)`. In example, with the code:

```
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:,:), allocatable   ::BB, RR
    integer                 ::i, j, ierr, n, m
    real, parameter             ::k = 4.0, l = 1.0

    n=3 !Dimension vector
    m=3 !Dimension del segundo orden

    allocate(RR(n,m), stat=ierr)
    allocate(BB(n,m), stat=ierr)

    forall(i = 1:size(BB(:,1)), j=1:size(BB(1,:)))
        BB(i,j)=i+j
        RR(i,j) = 0 
    endforall

    do i=1,size(BB(:,1))
        print *, BB(:,i)
    enddo

    call matSparXMat(k, l, BB, RR)

    do i=1,size(BB(:,1))
        print *, BB(:,i)
    enddo
```

I get the output:

```
 2.000000       3.000000       4.000000    
   3.000000       4.000000       5.000000    
   4.000000       5.000000       6.000000  

  4.6526092E+33   3.000000      1.9366391E+31
   3.000000       4.000000       5.000000    
   4.000000       5.000000       6.000000
```

In which you can see that the values of `BB` has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it went wrong here:

```
do i = 2, (size(R)-2)                      !<---- here
   call matsparXVec(k,l,B(i,:),R(i,:))
   R(i,:)=R(i-1,:)+R(i,:)
enddo
```

`size(R)=9` but `size(R(:,1))=3`. However, using gfortran I do get the correct output with an error

```
*** glibc detected *** ./sparse_mults: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000014e4010 ***
```

But when I use ifort 2013, I get the value `1.93...E+31` that you have in the top right corner, but otherwise it is correct. Not sure what is going on, but if I come up with something I'll let you know.

Comment: Right! I was also committing the same mistake in this lines:

`call matsparXVec(k,l,B(size(B),:),R(size(R),:)) !<- Here
 R(size(R),:) = R(size(R),:) + l * B(size(B)-1,:) !<- Here`


Replacing `size(B)` and `size(R)` by `size(B(:,1))` and `size(R(:,1))` solves the whole problem.

Comment: Also: my opinion is that you should pass the arguments `m` and `n` to the subroutines, so then you don't have to worry about `SIZE(B(:,1))` calls.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `size` calls to set a local `m` and `n` at the beginning of the function; I prefer this sometimes because then you don't need more arguments. Also, it's usually preferred to use `size(B,1)` to get the size of the dimension, rather than `size(B(:,1))`.